# Keep getting 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' is marked IsAuthenticated = true error c# .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

I'm creating an .NET Core MVC application.
I have to different functions: Get all api data, and Post api data (form data).

This is the controller for Get the data:

```
[Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Overzicht()
        {
            var httpcontext = HttpContext;

            //var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");

            //var service = new ExactOnlineService();

            var refreshTokenClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            //var authInfo = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("ClientCookie");

            //await HttpContext.SignInAsync("ClientCookie", authInfo.Principal, authInfo.Properties);

            var service = new ExactOnlineService();

            await service.RefreshAccessToken(httpcontext, refreshTokenClient);

            //await service.PostCustomers(httpcontext);

            var customers = await service.GetCustomers(httpcontext);

            //await service.PostCustomers(httpcontext);

            //await service.RefreshAccessToken(httpcontext, refreshTokenClient);

            return View(customers);
        }
```

This is the controller for Posting the data

```
[HttpPost]
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CompanyName,FirstName,LastName,Salutation,Street,HouseNumber,HouseNumberAddition,Email,CountryID,Tel,LnaguageID,City,ZipCode,State")] Customer customer)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var httpcontext = HttpContext;

                var cust = customer;

                var service = new ExactOnlineService();

                await service.PostCustomers(httpcontext, customer);

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Overzicht));
            }
            return View(customer);
        }
```

When I'm on the "Overzicht" page, the cookie has been set, and the authorization is done.
Next, I'm going to the "Create" page and I'm getting the `'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' is marked IsAuthenticated = true` error.

When i'm deleting all the cookies, I'm able to go to the "Create" page. But when I go to the "Overzicht" page agian, the cookie is set. When I go back to the "Create" page, I'm getting the `'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' is marked IsAuthenticated = true` error again.

I've no idea what i'm doing wrong. I think it has something to do with the Cookies or with `[Authorize]` and `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` in the same project.

Can someone help me?